# Laravel deleting wrong Model with delete() call

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My model `Service` has a composite primary key, I'm trying to delete only version 2, but on calling `delete()` of that model, Eloquent also deletes the first version (which has the same `id`, but different `version`.

```
dump(Service::where("id", $serviceId)->where("version", 1)->count());

$service = Service::where("id", $serviceId)->where("version", 2)->first();
$service->delete();

dd(Service::where("id", $serviceId)->where("version", 1)->count());
```

The output of the `dump()` before the `delete()` is 1, and output of `dd()` is 0. I've verified the `$service` is the correct model with the correct `version`.

Here's my key setup on the Services table:

`$table->unique(["id", "item_id", "version"]);`

What's going wrong here? Is my code wrong, or is something going wrong with Eloquent?

Comment: I'm guessing laravel deletes by primary id only. Why not just as incrementing primary id's seems pretty edge case to not do that?

Comment: I think it is because eloquent does not handle composite keys very well.  Does `Service::where("id", $serviceId)->where("version", 2)->delete();` works for you?

Comment: Better explanation and also a workaround here [https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5355](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5355)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `delete()` method from [Builder](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_delete):

`Service::where("id", $serviceId)->where("version", 2)->delete();`

---

Eloquent does not handle properly composite primary keys. The `delete()` method from [Model](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_delete) delete all records that matches the `id` field.

Here is a better explanation and a workaround if you really want to use composite primary keys: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5355

And from [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#composite-primary-keys).